# Bluetooth Network access point setup

Tags: networking, bluetooth, network-bridge, bluez

I want to setup a ubuntu device as bluetooth NAP, then other linux device(Raspberry pi or UDOO) can access the internet by connecting the ubuntu device using bluetooth.

My ubuntu device is server iso, it has only work on terminal. And also, it is using bluetooth USB for the bluetooth.

I have been spend long time to research, but doesn't have any idea in bluetooth NAP.

Thanks.